# In Mercurial (hg), how do you query the hg database for changeset information?

Tags: merge, mercurial, branch, changeset, transplant

I have a changeset, 32ada6b3ff3fd4b5d2d0e3da4ba72c5634da7857.  This changeset has been transplanted and merged into various branches.  Following a transplant from branch to branch is fairly easy. The transplant information shows up doing an "hg log -r 32ada6b3ff3fd4b5d2d0e3da4ba72c5634da7857".  From there, it's just an iterative process.

How can I find out what branches this changeset has been **merged** or **branched** to?  Is there a way to query the hg database for this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Branches** of descendants of `32ada6b3` are (in short syntax)

```
hg log -r "branch(32ada6b3::)"
```

there main change is only used  predicate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, I think you can accomplish that with [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets). For example:

```
hg log -r "heads(descendants(32ada6b....))"
```

will give you all changesets that have `32ada6b...` in their history and have no children.